# solaris: manifest associated to service?

Tags: solaris

I have set a service , a kind of rc.local on solaris
but i forgot name of xml manifest  associated.
How to see wich manifest is associated to a service?
Service is

```
svc:/site/rclocal:default
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command should help you:

```
svcs -l svc:/site/rclocal:default
```

and in result you will see something like

```
manifest     /lib/svc/manifest/site/local.xml
```